# Laravel - Make a check before the command "php artisan test"

Tags: testing, laravel-8, php-pest

I need to do a check before launching the `php artisan test` command.

I need this because I currently have 2 databases for DEV, one local and one shared with my collaborators. I want to prevent the tests from running on the shared database.

I already saw that I could create a [custom command with Laravel](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but I would like to know if there was a better solution ...

Thanks in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `.env.testing` file & define specific database name & credentials there, then test will use this file. For more restriction you can add below code block on your TestCase abstract class & `extends` that class on all of your Test Case classes.

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function setUp() :void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        
        if ( !file_exists(__DIR__.'/../.env.testing') ) {
            throw new \Exception('!!! Create .env.testing file !!!');
        }
    }
}
```

And in your test case classes

```
class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer!

I just saw that I have an .env.testing file with the right information but it doesn't work

I'm using PEST (I forgot to mention it I'm sorry). I saw that you have to run with the --env=testing option for it to work but that's not my goal

Comment: Finally I used the TestCase class and I was able to put a check that blocks the launch! Thanks a lot!